# if $f(x,y)=\phi(x-cy)+\phi(x+cy)$ then $f_{22}=c^2f_{11}.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Any hint how to solve this:

Show that if $f(x,y)=\phi(x-cy)+\phi(x+cy)$ then $f_{22}=c^2f_{11}.$

I don't know how to proceed with this .Kindly help with some hint how to solve this...

Comment: Just differentiate twice with respect to each argument (assume that $\phi$ is twice differentiable, it holds in a generalised sense even if it isn't, but assume $\phi$ nice).

Comment: @DanielFischer I tried the same way but did not get answer...don't know where am I wrong..

Comment: What did you get when you tried it?

Comment: @DanielFischer Proving the weak form is a pain though, compared to these simple computations.

Comment: You need to know a certain topic from calculus: "chain rule for partial derivatives" ... look for it in your textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task is to show that a $C^2$ function $\phi$ can be used to build a solution to the wave equation
$$\partial_{yy} f(x,y) = c^2 \partial_{xx} f(x,y)\\
f(x,y) = \phi(x-cy) + \phi(x+cy)$$
Not sure why you write $f_{11}$ (like matrix indexing).
To prove this, just differentiate using the chain rule:
$$\begin{align*}
\partial_{yy} f(x,y) & = \partial_y ( -c\phi'(x-cy) + c\phi'(x+cy) ) \\
& = (-c)^2 \phi''(x-cy) + c^2 \phi''(x+cy) \\
& = c^2 (\phi''(x-cy) + \phi''(x+cy)) \\
&= c^2 \partial_x (\phi'(x-cy) + \phi'(x+cy)) \\
& = c^2 \partial_{xx} (\phi(x-cy) + \phi(x+cy)) \\
& =c^2 \partial_{xx} f(x,y)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: The notation $f_{ij}$ is uncommon, but not rare, and in my opinion it is better than the standard ones.

Comment: @GitGud I think it should be emphasized that $\partial_{ij}$ or $D_{ij}$ is an operator wich gives a (multi)linear form and not "just" a function.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I think it should be emphasized that functions do not depend on variables, functions are functions and $f_i$ is the derivative with respect to the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate, regardless of the variable you'll use for it. And no problem.

Comment: @GitGud Let $f:\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^d$. How would you index $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i} f(x,y)$? Also note that $\partial_{ij} f$ doesn't use the variable names either. Only when the variables are specified (like $\partial_{xx} f(x,y)$) I use them.

Comment: Partial derivatives only have meaning, to me, for scalar functions. I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @GitGud I'd mean a gradient vector $(\partial_{y_i} f_l(x,y))_{l=1}^d$ by that but you can set $d=1$ if you want, then you have a scalar ;)

Comment: For $d=1$, I interpret $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i} f(x,y)$ as being $\left(\partial _{n+i}f\right)(x,y)$.

Comment: @GitGud Allright. This will only become troublesome for a countable dimension, like $f: \ell^\infty(\mathbb N) \times \ell^1 (\mathbb N) \to \mathbb R, f(\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}) = \sum_n a_n b_n$ but that's fine. I see your notation is valid but I think it may become disadvantageous because you must take care of "shift" indexing.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(-c\phi'(x-cy)+c\phi'(x+cy)\right)=c^2\phi''(x-cy)+c^2\phi''(x+cy)$$

Now compute $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ and check if the equality holds.